# Find the distribution given the probability generating function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions

*Let X be a random variable with probability generating function*

$G(s)=1-\frac{b}{1-c} - \frac{bs}{1-cs}$

*What distribution has X?*

So, using the p.g.f property and induction hypothesis

$P(X=n)=\frac{G^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$

$G^{(1)}(s)=-b(1-cs)^{-2}$

$G^{(2)}(s)=-2b(1-cs)^{-3}c^1$

$G^{(3)}(s)=-6b(1-cs)^{-4}c^2$

$G^{(4)}(s)=-24b(1-cs)^{-5}c^3$

...

$G^{(n)}(s)=-(n!)b(1-cs)^{-(n+1)}c^{n-1}$

Then, $P(X=0)=1-\frac{b}{1-c}$ and for n>1:

$P(X=n)=-bc^{(n-1)}$

**P(X=x) table:**

| 0 | 1 | 2 | ... | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1-\frac{b}{1-c}$ | $-b$ | $-bc$ | ... | $-bc^{n-1}$ |

I think that's correct but didn't manage to find the distribution...

Answer (score 1):

Your computations are correct, aside from a factor of $-1$ on the derivatives of $G$ (due to an error in the question). Indeed $\mathbb P(X=0) = 1-\frac b{1-c}$ and $\mathbb P(X=n) = bc^{n-1}$ for $n\geqslant 1$. It follows that
$$
X = \left(1-\frac b{1-c}\right)\mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(n) + Y,
$$
where $Y\sim\mathsf{Geo}(b)$ (and necessarily $b+c=1$).

Comment: I see. It's a shifted geometric distribution.
That (-1) really confused me, is the error in the question? Shouldn't be $G(s) = 1 - \frac{b}{1-c}(+)\frac{bs}{1-cs}$?

Comment: Yes, that is an error. A valid probability generating function must satisfy $G(0)=1$, for example.